# MySQL is not starting on XAMPP MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

So when I use XAMPP to start MySQL it turns into a yellow light but turned red at the end without any Application Log shown.

When I try to type

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

to start it, it shows error message as the followings:

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't
>   create/write to file
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MAC-0122.local.err'
>   (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

I have researched a bit and tried to `chown` on the respective file directory but the error still stays the same.

I tried to find mysql in process and kill but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change some chmod settings but i don't know how to do that.

Better to use mamp server I'm using mamp it's really good in mac where xampp is perfect for windows.

Here is the link https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I would like to solve the problem of XAMPP first.